# adding a hoverstatus to small parts of an image

Tags: jquery, html, css

Depicted below is a floor plan which is displayed in a regular html file. It is just 1 big image which should have the numbered element blocks pixel perfectly placed over it before a style can even be applied.

The numbered boxes need to have a hover status that turns their background color orange and their number white.

I'd like to know if its possible to achieve this without having to resort to flash. Is it?

[image: floorplan]

Comment: It is possible if you convert all the sections into separate elements and position them as in the image. No flash needed, but it could take a while to get right.

Comment: Yes. That is possible. With CSS :hover pseudo class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's entirely possible. Normally elements in HTML are positioned in a 'flow', but you can take them out using `absolute` positioning. This allows you to give percentage- or pixel-based values to any of the `top`, `left`,  `bottom`, `right` properties and the elements will be positioned at that location offset to their nearest ancestor element with position set to `relative`, `absolute` or `fixed`.

Here's a reduced example containing a couple of rooms from your image. You should be able to extend it by copy and pasting then adding new rooms into the markup, and changing their shape and position by giving new ID-based `#roomXXXX` rules in the CSS.

http://jsfiddle.net/barney/kBvsr/

**EDIT:** Amended example to allow hover in IE6 as pointed out by @Marcio.

Comment: This looks like its exactly what I need. 1 quick question though, if using absolute positioning, won't that mess up other elements in the doc that have regular relative positioning? (elements outside this floorplan that is, think header/footer and such...

Comment: Nope - `absolute` elements are taken out of the document flow, so that they don't really affect the rest of the elements in the document. They can of course appear above them etc, but as long as you keep them wrapped in the `relative`ly positioned `.floorplan` div, they will be limited to appearing within there.

Comment: Hey @Amelia – could you mark this as the answer if it provides you with a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Define a class name to all the boxes with numbers and use CSS pseudo class as follows

```
           .classname:hover
             {
            background-color:color;
              font-color:color;
               }
```

Comment: If it needs to work in all browsers :hover doesn't work in IE 6 so you should be careful with that.

Comment: Not true. While there are a lot of caveats to using `:hover` in IE6, if applied to links (`a`) without any `filter`s, it should be fine.

Comment: You're missing the point. I probably wasn't clear enough in my questioning, but the thing is those boxes need to be placed at exactly their corresponding position before any hover can be applied. So what is needed first is a way to position the elements so theyre placed on this map (which is just 1 big image).

Answer (score 0):

If the whole thing, including the boxes and numbers are an image, you can't change the images  per se with CSS using the hover attributes and trying to change the color.  You can overlay s and have them appear above or you can overlay another version of each box with an image.  Using Photoshop/Image Ready you can slice up the image and create the hover-over effects; exporting the whole thing as a usable web page.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a couple of ways to do it. They all rely on html5 though. I'd use a transparent canvas placed in-front of the image. My natural inclination would be to overlay the image with a coloured rectangle, though it's not too much trouble to access the pixels in the image directly and create an accurate 'negative' of the hovered area.

Following on from a quesrtion that asked about highlighting imgmap area tags on hover, I came up with the following solution. You can click to define points on the right-hand image (min 3 for usefull shape), click add poly, then hover the same area on the image on the left.

Please consider it more as an example for a way of highlighting part of an image, rather than how-to make a image-map area defining-tool.. :)

Oh, before I forget - you can look at the page in developer-mode to copy the created area tags - I really should have copied them into a text-area for easy copy paste..

Code is tested with Chrome.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
var canvas, hdc, markerImg;
var curPoints;

function byId(e){return document.getElementById(e);}

function canvasClick2(e)
{
    e = e || event;

    var x, y;

    x = e.offsetX;
    y = e.offsetY;

    curPoints.push(x);
    curPoints.push(y);

    hdc.drawImage(markerImg, x- markerImg.width/2, y-markerImg.height/2);

    n = curPoints.length;
    var str = ''
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if (i != 0)
            str += ', ';
        str += curPoints[i];
    }
    byId('coords').innerHTML = str;
}

function myInit()
{
    curPoints = new Array();
    canvas = byId('canvas1');
    hdc = canvas.getContext('2d');
    markerImg = new Image();

    // just a 5x5 pixel +
    markerImg.src = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHklEQVQIW2NkQID/QCYjiAsmoABFEMRBAThVYmgHAAhoBQWHhfyYAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC";

    canvas.addEventListener('click', canvasClick2, false);

    var img = byId('img1');
    canvas.setAttribute('width', img.width);
    canvas.setAttribute('height', img.height);
//  canvas.style.backgroundImage = 'url(img/gladiators.png)';
    canvas.style.backgroundImage = 'url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rw5pL.png)';


    var x,y, w,h;

    // get it's position and width+height
    x = img.offsetLeft;
    y = img.offsetTop;
    w = img.clientWidth;
    h = img.clientHeight;

    // move the canvas, so it's contained by the same parent as the image
    var imgParent = img.parentNode;
    var can = byId('canvas2');
    imgParent.appendChild(can);

    // place the canvas in front of the image
    can.style.zIndex = 1;

    // position it over the image
    can.style.left = x+'px';
    can.style.top = y+'px';

    // make same size as the image
    can.setAttribute('width', w+'px');
    can.setAttribute('height', h+'px');

    var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
    ctx.lineWidth = 3;
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
}

function myClear()
{
    hdc.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    curPoints.length = 0;
    byId('coords').innerHTML = '';
}

function myAddShapePoly()
{
    var src, tgt = byId('imgMap1'), coordStr;

    src = byId('coords');
    coordStr = src.innerHTML;

    var newArea = document.createElement('area');
    newArea.setAttribute('shape', 'polygon');
    newArea.setAttribute('coords', coordStr);
    newArea.setAttribute('title', 'polygon');

    newArea.setAttribute('onclick', 'alert("area clicked");');

    newArea.onmouseout = myLeave;
    newArea.onmouseover = function(){myHover2(this);};

    tgt.appendChild(newArea);
    myClear();
}


function myHover2(element)
{
    var hoveredElement = element;
    var coordStr = element.getAttribute('coords');
    var areaType = element.getAttribute('shape');

    switch (areaType)
    {
        case 'polygon':
        case 'poly':
            fillPoly(coordStr);
            break;

        case 'rect':
            fillRect(coordStr);
    }
//  byId('img1').style.cursor = 'pointer';
}


function myLeave()
{
    var canvas = byId('canvas2');
    var hdc = canvas.getContext('2d');
    hdc.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
//  byId('img1').style.cursor = '';
}


function fillRect(coOrdStr)
{
    var canvas = byId('canvas2');
    var hdc = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var mCoords = coOrdStr.split(',');
    var top, left, bot, right;
    left = mCoords[0];
    top = mCoords[1];
    right = mCoords[2];
    bot = mCoords[3];
    var canvas = byId('myCanvas');
    var tmp = hdc.fillStyle;

    hdc.fillStyle = "rgba(255,0,0,0.3);";
    hdc.fillRect(left,top,right-left,bot-top);
    hdc.strokeRect(left,top,right-left,bot-top);
    hdc.fillStyle = tmp;
}
// takes a string that contains coords eg - "227,307,261,309, 339,354, 328,371, 240,331"
// draws a line from each co-ord pair to the next - assumes starting point needs to be repeated as ending point.
function fillPoly(coOrdStr)
{
    var mCoords = coOrdStr.split(',');
    var i, n;
    n = mCoords.length;
    var canvas = byId('canvas2');
    var hdc = canvas.getContext('2d');

    hdc.beginPath();
    hdc.moveTo(mCoords[0], mCoords[1]);
    for (i=2; i<n; i+=2)
    {
        hdc.lineTo(mCoords[i], mCoords[i+1]);
    }
    hdc.lineTo(mCoords[0], mCoords[1]);

    tmp=hdc.fillStyle;
    hdc.fillStyle = "rgba(255,0,0,0.3);";
    hdc.stroke();
    hdc.fill();
    hdc.fillStyle = tmp;
}

</script>
<style>
body
{
    background-color: gray;
}

#canvas1
{
    cursor: crosshair;
}
#canvas2
{
    pointer-events: none;       /* make the canvas transparent to the mouse - needed since canvas is position infront of image */
    position: absolute;
}
.heading
{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 24px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload='myInit();'>
    <div align='center'>
        <img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rw5pL.png' id='img1' usemap='#imgMap1'/>
            <map name='imgMap1' id='imgMap1'>
            </map>
        <canvas id='canvas2'></canvas>

        <canvas id='canvas1' width='200' height='200'></canvas>
        <br>
        <input type='button' onclick='myClear();' value='clear'/>
        <input type='button' onclick='myAddShapePoly();' value='addPolygon'/>
        <br>
        <span id='coords'></span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```